# aptana 3.2 ruby code assist/completion doesn't work

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, aptana

for example :

```
a="hello"
a.
```

when we try to enter "a." and press "Ctrl+Space", there is now appropriate appear

where is wrong?

any ideas will be appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptana studio 3 now supports code autocompletion(CTRL+space) for Ruby/Rails.